# Android: Error in functional testing

Tags: android

I have an `Android Tab Layout` with swipeable views.

The file structure is as follows:

There is an activity class: `TabMainActivity.java`, under this activity, there is a `Fragment` class named  `bookLockerFragment.java`.This fragment class is linked to an XML file which contains various buttons. Code is as follows,

```
public class bookLockerFragment extends Fragment {
Button btnSis;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booklocker, container, false);
    btnSis = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSis);
 }
.......
}
```

I wrote some code to test the functionality whether I can launch the next activity(`PopulateLockerList.java`) when I click the `Button`, manually tested and it works
however, i get the error: `junit.framework.AssertionFailedError` when i run the `junit` test. Below is the test code:

```
package com.example.mobilelog6.test;

 public class bookLockerFragmentTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<TabMainActivity>{
     private static final String NEW_TEXT = "new text";
     private TabMainActivity activity;

     public bookLockerFragmentTest() {
        super(TabMainActivity.class);
      }

      protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
            activity = getActivity();
          }

            public void testFragment() {
            Fragment frag = 

             activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Search/Book Lockers");                     


            Button sisButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSis);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", sisButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "SIS",                 

            sisButton.getText());

            Button soeButton =(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSoesoss);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", soeButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "SOE/SOSS", 

             soeButton.getText());

            Button lkcsbButton = 

              (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLkcsb);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", lkcsbButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "LKCSB", 

                lkcsbButton.getText());

            Button soaButton = 

               (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSoasol);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", soaButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "SOA/SOL", 

               soaButton.getText());

            Button allSchoolsButton = 

              (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnAllSchools);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", allSchoolsButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "All Schools", 

              allSchoolsButton.getText());

            Button lv2Button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnLvl2);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", lv2Button);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "Lv 2", 

              lv2Button.getText());

            Button viewLockerButton = 

                (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnView);
            assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", viewLockerButton);
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "View Locker 

                 Selection", viewLockerButton.getText());

            ActivityMonitor monitor =
                    getInstrumentation().
                      addMonitor(PopulateLockerList.class.getName(), null, 

               false);

            TouchUtils.clickView(this, allSchoolsButton);
            TouchUtils.clickView(this, viewLockerButton);

          PopulateLockerList startedActivity = (PopulateLockerList) monitor
                .waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);
            assertNotNull(startedActivity);

            ListView mListView = (ListView) 

              startedActivity.findViewById(R.id.listViewLockers);
            TextView entryView = (TextView) mListView.getChildAt(0);
            String viewText = entryView.getText().toString();
            assertEquals("Incorrect label of the listview 0", "View Locker                 

            Selection", viewText);
        }


             }
```

Error at this line:

```
 assertNotNull(startedActivity);
```

Please help

Comment: Are you getting error, or your case is getting failed ?

Comment: my test case failed, but the testing app works as per normal when i tested it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could solve it.

1. You have to be sure the package of the project you are testing is declared in the manifest of the project you are using to test it, like this:

Note: I suppose your "targetpackage" may be "com.example.mobilelog6"

1. You have to be sure your activity TabMainActivity starts your activity PopulateLockerList
2. In your method testFragment() of your class bookLockerFragmentTest, you have to "simulate" the event used in your TabMainActivity (i.e. with click event of button) to start the activity PopulateLockerList before call

   PopulateLockerList startedActivity = (PopulateLockerList) monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);

I have seen you call 2 events before call

```
monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000)

      TouchUtils.clickView(this, allSchoolsButton); 
and
      TouchUtils.clickView(this, viewLockerButton);
```

So, maybe you only need to start your activity PopulateLockerList from one of this buttons in your activity TabMainActivity. 
For instance:

```
Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAllSchools);
           addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {                  

                   showSecondaryActivity();
               }
           });
private void showSecondaryActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,PopulateLockerList .class));
        }
```

I expect, this can help you